# How to automatically check the checkbox if the particular checkboxes are checked

Tags: excel

I am having an excel sheet to track the watched episodes.

[image: Image of the Excel]

I want if checkboxes besides episodes 1,2,3 of season1 are checked automatically the checkbox besides season1 should be checked and similar should happen with season2 episodes once the episodes besides it are checked.

Note: I am new to excel checkboxes.

Thanks & Regards,

Parth.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it:

*For the episode checkboxes:*

- Right-clicking a checkbox will get you to the `Format Control` options.
- On the `Control` tab link each episode checkbox to a separate cell.
- On the `Protection` tab make sure the checkbox aren't protected.

*For the season checkboxes:*

- Link the checkbox to a cell.
- Make sure the checkbox is protected.
- In the linked cell enter the formula: `=AND(C5:C7)` where `C5:C7` are the linked cells for the episodes.
  This formula will return TRUE when each of the referenced cells is TRUE, or FALSE otherwise.  This will then be reflected in the checkbox.

Protect the sheet otherwise checking the season checkbox will overwrite the formula.

[image]

Comment: Actually, I do not want to lick the episode cells as it will give me an additional column which I do not want.

Comment: You could change the cell format to white text and place the checkbox directly over the cell and it would look like your picture.  I just placed the checkbox in the next column for demo purposes.